# How to fit a Storage Options bike cam helmet mount

Tags: accessories, camera

I recently bought a helmet and handbar moutable camera made by a firm called storage options.  The instructions do not explain how to fit the strap for helmet attachment.  It consists of a ring of elastic with a further piece of elastic attached at right angles to the ring to form a half circle above the ring.  The camera mount is at the T where this extra piece attaches to the ring, and is oriented in the same direction as the extra piece.

Here is a photo of the strap.  I think that the camera is supposed to be inserted in an upwards direction into the area above the buckle on the lower strap (although this doesn't seem like a secure mount).

[image]

Here is a photo of the camera in situ on a helmet.  As you can see it's not entirely clear how the straps are arranged from this photo

[image]

Does anyone know how to fit this to my helmet (which has a sun visor and to the best of my knowledge is a [Giro Venti](http://www.giro.com/us_en/products/men/road/venti.html))?

Comment: A diagram or photograph would be useful.

Comment: @tom77 Added a picture above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's designed so the bit at the top of the picture wraps around the helmet like a headband while the part of the strap that is making a "U" in the picture goes across the top.

To keep it from coming off, you'll need it to be fairly tight. This is okay with the helmets that are similar to skateboarding/snowboarding helmets (hard shell), but can make some of the more pricey (lighter) bike helmets lose integrity.

If you aren't going hard down single track, this will probably be okay, but be ready for it to slip off if you are doing anything that rocks the boat much.

Comment: I'm a commuter cyclist, so it's unlikely to face anything rougher than the odd pothole.  The visor on my helmet (a mid range polystyrene and plastic one which is probably a Giro Venti) seems to prevent the strap going round the front of the helmet in the manner you describe.  If it sits further back than the visor it seems to slide off.  I've added a promotional photo of the strap in situ to the question - to me at least, it's still less than clear.

Comment: It may still work in your helmet, but as you've discovered, you will need to get it below the visor (or remove the visor...most will pop off and back on...I think this is true for the Venti, but I don't have one handy to look at).

Answer (score 0):

I've just bought one and am puzzling over the same problem.
My strap has two elastic loops that encircle the main strap (the bit that should be horizontal in use), I thought that these were to hold the camera, as it would be considerably more secure than being wedged under the buckle of the top strap as illustrated in the photo. It took a lot of effort to get the camera into one off these elastic loops and when I had,I found that it had damaged the stitching.
I actually managed to get the strap round my helmet (had to take off the peak visor thing to do it), but it was so tight it threatened to ping off at any moment. The stitching here looked under stress as well.
I phoned the retailer, who offered a refund.
Trouble is, the camera seems excellent & I haven't had any problems with the handlebar mount, I just want to have the camera looking where I'm facing.

Comment: Welcome to the site, but please be aware that this is not a discussion forum. Please use the *post answer* button only for actual answers.